# How can I communicate with external python script from Django server

Tags: python, django, websocket, client-server, rfid

I have a Django server running in my pc and a client browser running into a Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi has a RFID-RC522 reader which may read nfc tags. My idea is to write a python script on the client side (RPi) that detect when a RFID card is read and send the read rfid id to the Django Server in order to login a user. Mi question is, How can I communicate with the server using this external python script?

Im using this [SimpleMFRC522 Library](https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python) to read from rfid reader.

The desired workflow is:

- A user access to the WebApp using a local IP ("192.168.0.105:8000").
- Django server respond serving the login page.
- The user wants to login with the RFID card, and bring the card to the reader.
- The reader, running in a external python, send the id of the card to Django Server.
- Django server autenticate the user.

Comment: Take a look at this; https://github.com/joaohenriquef/rfid-access-control